# is tracking pixel can execute javascript from remote server?

Tags: javascript, servlets, tracking, local-storage, pixel

I want put tracking pixel on 3rd party html file, which will call a servlet that will return javascript. This javascript should get a value from the local storage and report it to other servlet. For example:

Tracking Pixel:

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/report" width="1" height="1">
```

The report servlet will return the following javascript:

```
var value= localStorage.getItem("myLocalStorageKey");
var serverUrl = "www.myserver.com/myservlet?value=" + value;
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", serverUrl, true);
xmlHttp.send("");
```

This doesn't work because the src property is not expect to handle javascript.
Is there any way I can accomplish this?
If the javascript will be called from the 3rd party html page, it won't be able to get the value from the local storage, because the value was entered from "myserver.com" domain, and not from the 3rd party domain.

Any idea???

Thanks,
Dani

Comment: Same origin security policies are designed to stop exactly what you're doing - other domains snooping on local properties that aren't supposed to be available to those other domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work, period. Javascrsipt has a 'same origin' security policy for xmlhttprequests. The source of this script would be YOUR server, so it cannot contact any other server EXCEPT yours.

You can get around it somewhat using JSONP instead, which dynamically builds/inserts a full `<script>...</script>` tag/code set into the page's DOM, but then you're still stuck with the fact that you're loading this via an `<img>` tag, which won't execute the code anyways.

Instead, consider doing something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourserver/track_me.js"></script>
```

and serve up the jsonp-creating code with that script.

Comment: If he has control over how the tracking pixel is injected, he maybe could inject the script tag instead.

Comment: If I'll call the script with src="http://yourserver/track_me.js",
is the javascript will run on "yourserver" domain or on the domain of the html page? 
In other words, will the javascript be able to retrieve values from the local storage that were entered by "yourserver" domain?

Comment: JS always runs locally, but with the rights/permissions of the originating server. If you load the js from your server, then it can do anything with stuff that's also originated from  your server. If it's loaded from some other server, then it can't touch stuff from your server at all.

Comment: Well, it's not working.
The javascript runs within the domain of the html page, so value I've entered to the local storage from yourserver domain cannot be read from the html page domain. Any idea?